# How to run testcafe from docker on remote selenium grid

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid, testcafe

I want to run testcafe tests in the browser installed on remote machine using [selenium grid docker](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) image (selenium/standalone-chrome-debug).

I'm able to execute testcafe tests in this remote browser from my local machine using command:

`SELENIUM_SERVER=http://<remote machine IP>:4444/wd/hub testcafe selenium:chrome tests/`

I can see that tests are executing and preview them in the browser when I connect to machine/docker container using VNC. Everything works perfectly.

The problem is when instead of using above command I'm trying to execute tests from my local machine using docker. This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
 my-app:
    image: my-app:0.1
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
 auit:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.auit.testcafe
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
      - "1338:1338"
    shm_size: 2G
    environment:
    - SELENIUM_SERVER=http://<remote machine IP>:4444/wd/hub
    depends_on:
    - my-app
    entrypoint: ["/opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh", "selenium:chrome", "/tests"]
```

The content of `Dockerfile.auit.testcafe`:

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe
WORKDIR /
USER root
COPY ./tests /tests
RUN npm install testcafe-browser-provider-selenium
```

So, when I run:

```
docker-compose up auit
```

the browser is launched in my selenium grid, but it is trying to connect to IP of my local docker container instead of my machine. I was trying to use `--hostname` parameter to set IP of my local machine, but I'm receiving an error:

```
ERROR The specified "<my IP>" hostname cannot be resolved to the current machine.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can the Selenium server access your local machine by the hostname rather than IP? If so, try the following approach.

Add the `extra_hosts` parameter to `docker-compose.yml`

```
auit:
   extra_hosts:
      - "my-hostname:127.0.0.1"
```

where `my-hostname` is the hostname of your local machine visible to the Selenium Grid.

Then specify this hostname in TestCafe's [--hostname parameter](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#--hostname-name) as you did with the IP.

However, if the use of the IP instead of the hostname is the only option, it will require more effort to implement this (if possible at all).